# Access cached images (Picasso)

Tags: android, caching, picasso

I'm having a loading screen where I fetch data belonging to the logged in user. Among this data is their profile images (three of them).

What I want to do is to cache the images when I download them with their URL in Loading screen. Then in the next activity I want to access the cached images to display them in that activity. So basically load all images in one activity to be used in another one. This way (I figured) I won't have to make a http request everytime user enters the activity where their profile image is shown. Which gives a better user experience.
So it's the matter of getting the images from cache to screen that I can't work out, cause I think I've loaded them into cache correctly, seen below.

Here's my current method in Loading Activity:

```
Backendless.Data.of(UserFileMapping.class).find(new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<UserFileMapping>>() {
            @Override
            public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<UserFileMapping> response) {
                Iterator<UserFileMapping> iterator = response.getCurrentPage().iterator();
                while(iterator.hasNext()){
                    UserFileMapping fileMapping = iterator.next();
                    String profile1 = fileMapping.profile_url;
                    String profile2 = fileMapping.profile_url_2;
                    String profile3 = fileMapping.profile_url_3;

                    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                            .load(profile1)
                            .fetch(new Callback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess() {
                                    continue_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    loading_text.setText("Done!");
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError() {
                                    //Make toast
                                }
                            });

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
                System.out.println("FAULT:" + fault.getCode());
            }
        });
```

It's the issue with downloading all three images at once as well, but that isn't as important as the caching question. If  you have a good idea on this in addition to the cache issue I would gladly like to hear it too.